# Create One Table from Two Separate Tables Relative to the Most Recent Date

Tags: mysql, sql, finance

For the life of me, can't figure out the syntax for this problem.  Have two tables that I need to join into one...no problem there, but getting tripped up on the most recent date piece.  Essentially, I need to iterate through each row of T1 and then find the most recent date in T2 for the same Ticker and then join the two tables together in the column structure below.  Basically, showing the most recent day's information inline with the recorded day in T1.

Two mysql Tables:

T1

```
Ticker   OpenPrice    Date   
AAPL        220       2019-03-01 
GOOG        300       2019-03-25
AMZN        950       2019-03-17
AMZN        925       2019-03-29
AAPL        250       2019-03-07
GOOG        355       2019-03-29
```

T2

```
Ticker   ClosePrice   Date
AAPL        220       2019-03-02
GOOG        335       2019-03-21
AMZN        925       2019-03-24
AMZN        955       2019-03-08
AAPL        250       2019-03-18
GOOG        340       2019-03-26
TSLA        1         2019-03-04
```

New Joined Table Needs to Be (Column Order Doesn't Really Matter):
Ticker | OpenPrice (from T1)| Date (from T1) | ClosePrice (from T2) | Most Recent Date (from T2)

So results if joining above tables would be:
NOTE: First AAPL record in T1 wouldn't show up as there is no date before 03-01 on T2

```
GOOG        300       2019-03-25     335       2019-03-21
AMZN        950       2019-03-17     955       2019-03-08
AMZN        925       2019-03-29     925       2019-03-24
AAPL        250       2019-03-07     220       2019-03-02
GOOG        355       2019-03-29     340       2019-03-26
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery to get the date that you want:

```
select t1.*,
       (select max(t2.date)
        from t2
        where t2.ticker = t1.ticker and
              t2.date <= t1.date
       ) as t2_date
from t1;
```

Then, join this back to get the full record:

```
select . . .  -- choose the columns you want
from (select t1.*,
             (select max(t2.date)
              from t2
              where t2.ticker = t1.ticker and
                    t2.date <= t1.date
             ) as t2_date
      from t1
     ) t1 join
     t2
     on t2.ticker = t1.ticker and t2.date = t1.t2_date;
```